# Java String Replace Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am doing some string replace in SQL on the fly.

```
MySQLString = " a.account=b.account ";
MySQLString = " a.accountnum=b.accountnum ";
```

Now if I do this

```
MySQLString.replaceAll("account", "account_enc");
```

the result will be

```
a.account_enc=b.account_enc
```

(This is good)

But look at 2nd result

```
a.account_enc_num=a.account_enc_num
```

(This is not good it should be `a.accountnum_enc=b.accountnum_enc`)

Please advise how can I achieve what I want with Java String Replace.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You should look at using a capturing group in your regex.

Comment: Next time, try to explain exactly what you need better, perhaps saying: **I want this, this and this to be replaced, but not this, this and this**.

Comment: @OscarMederos apologies, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> Is there anyway to tell in Regex only replace a.**account**=b.**account** or a.**accountnum**=b.**accountnum**. I do not want **accountname** to be replace with `_enc`

If I understand correctly you want to add `_enc` part only to `account` or `accountnum`. To do this you can use

```
MySQLString = MySQLString.replaceAll("\\baccount(num)?\\b", "$0_enc");
```

`(num)?` mean that `num` is optional so regex will accept `account` or `accountnum`

`\\b` at start mean that there can be no letters, numbers or "`_`" before `account` so it wont accept (affect) something like myaccount, or my_account.

`\\b` at the end will prevent other letters, numbers or "`_`" after account or accountnum.

Comment: @OscarMederos hope OP wont say now something like "but I want it to update only if two words that I am changing are identical" so no change in `a.account=b.accountnum` :) (I've seen that before :D)

Comment: @Pshemo I need to try it out in Java to be sure but if \\b prevents letters or  numbers or underscore before account will it catch a.account i.e. a. before account?

Comment: @user2101374 in `a.account` there is `dot` between `a` and `account` so it will accept `account` since dot is not number, letter or underscore. If you don't like the way it works don't be afraid to remove \\b :)

Comment: @Pshemo, works like a charm, thank you very much. Thanks to all who have replied, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to extrapolate from so few examples, but maybe what you want is:

```
MySQLString = MySQLString.replaceAll("account\\w*", "$0_enc");
```

which will append `_enc` to any sequence of letters, digits, and underscores that starts with `account`.

Comment: Hi Ruakh, this will even cause accountname to be changed to accountname_enc which I do not want, any other suggestion?

Comment: @user2101374: How can you tell that you want `accountnum_enc` but not `accountname_enc`?

Comment: Hi Ruakh, I have a list of columns in a file which I know I need to add enc. Actually enc stands for encrypted so only account number need to be changed to _enc. The column name containing account can either be called account or accountnum.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String s = " a.accountnum=b.accountnum ".replaceAll("(account[^ =]*)", "$1_enc");
```

it means replace any sequence characters which are not ' ' or '=' which starts the word "account" with the sequence found + "_enc".

$1 is a reference to group 1 in regex; group 1 is the expression in parenthesis (account[^ =]+), i.e. our sequence

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for details

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy, could you please explain the regex you have used? Apologies I am not very good at Regex want to understand does the regex you have used means

Comment: Evgeniy, wouldnt this even replace a.name=b.name with a.name_enc=b.name_enc? I only like to replace a.account=b.account to be a.account_enc=b.account_enc OR a.accountnum=b.accountnum to be a.accountnum_enc=b.accountnum_enc

Comment: It wont after I've fixed it :), now I think you have enough examples to make corrections to the regex.

Comment: It seems there is just one issue with this Regex, it will even convert a.accountname=b.accountname to a.accountname_enc=b.accountname_enc, correct? Is there anyway to tell in Regex only replace a.account=b.account or a.accountnum=b.accountnum, I do not want accountname to be replace with _enc. Thank you very much. Very much appreciated :)